# MonoMac Packaging Error

Tags: macos, mono, monomac

I am using MonoMac 3.0.6 with Mono Runtime 2.10.12 and I have created an app with it. So, I wanted to pack the MonoRuntime with it: went to it's options and selected to link "Framework SDKs Only". When I am building it I am getting this error:

Building: ThisSimpleApp (Debug|x86)
Performing main compilation...
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.12/bin/dmcs /noconfig "/out:/Users/shreyansh/Projects/ThisSimpleApp/ThisSimpleApp/bin/Debug/ThisSimpleApp.exe" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.12/lib/mono/4.0/System.dll" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.12/lib/mono/4.0/System.Xml.dll" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.12/lib/mono/4.0/System.Core.dll" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.12/lib/mono/4.0/System.Xml.Linq.dll" "/r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.12/lib/mono/4.0/System.Drawing.dll" "/r:/Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.MonoMac/MonoMac.dll" /nologo /warn:4 /debug:full /optimize- /codepage:utf8 /platform:x86 "/define:DEBUG"  /t:exe "/Users/shreyansh/Projects/ThisSimpleApp/ThisSimpleApp/MainWindow.cs" "/Users/shreyansh/Projects/ThisSimpleApp/ThisSimpleApp/MainWindowController.cs" "/Users/shreyansh/Projects/ThisSimpleApp/ThisSimpleApp/MainWindow.designer.cs" "/Users/shreyansh/Projects/ThisSimpleApp/ThisSimpleApp/Main.cs" "/Users/shreyansh/Projects/ThisSimpleApp/ThisSimpleApp/AppDelegate.cs" "/Users/shreyansh/Projects/ThisSimpleApp/ThisSimpleApp/AppDelegate.designer.cs" 
Build complete -- 0 errors, 0 warnings

Updating application manifest

Merging Mono Runtime into app bundle
/Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.MonoMac/mmp -linksdkonly "-minos=10.6" -o "/Users/shreyansh/Projects/ThisSimpleApp/ThisSimpleApp/bin/Debug" -n "ThisSimpleApp" -a "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.12/lib/mono/4.0/System.dll" -a "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.12/lib/mono/4.0/System.Xml.dll" -a "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.12/lib/mono/4.0/System.Core.dll" -a "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.12/lib/mono/4.0/System.Xml.Linq.dll" -a "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.12/lib/mono/4.0/System.Drawing.dll" -a "/Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.MonoMac/MonoMac.dll" "/Users/shreyansh/Projects/ThisSimpleApp/ThisSimpleApp/bin/Debug/ThisSimpleApp.exe"

Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for MonoMac.Bundler.Driver ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: ApplicationName='pkg-config', CommandLine='--variable=prefix mono-2', CurrentDirectory=''
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_noshell (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x00000] in :0 
  at MonoMac.Bundler.Driver.RunCommand (System.String path, System.String args, System.String[] env, System.String& output) [0x00000] in :0 
  at MonoMac.Bundler.Driver..cctor () [0x00000] in :0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for MonoMac.Bundler.Driver ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: ApplicationName='pkg-config', CommandLine='--variable=prefix mono-2', CurrentDirectory=''
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_noshell (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x00000] in :0 
  at MonoMac.Bundler.Driver.RunCommand (System.String path, System.String args, System.String[] env, System.String& output) [0x00000] in :0 
  at MonoMac.Bundler.Driver..cctor () [0x00000] in :0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
mmp exited with code 1

---------------------- Done ----------------------

Build: 1 error, 0 warnings

and it exits...

I wanted to ask if anyone can help me as I have been struggling with this for a month now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the exception states the `pkg-config` tool could not be found.

It used to be copied into `/usr/bin` in older releases of Mono but was in conflict with other packages (e.g. macport) so it's not copied anymore.

One way to fix this is to create a symlink (from `/usr/bin/pkg-config`) to the `pkg-config` tool shipped with Mono, under `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/...`

Comment: can you please explain more?